# how to return shared_ptr to current object from inside the "this" object itself

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr

I have an instance of View class (instantiated somewhere in the Controller owning object using shared_ptr)

```
class ViewController {
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<View> view_;
};
```

This view has also method "hitTest()" that should return this view's shared_ptr to the outside world

```
class View {
...
public:
std::shared_ptr<UIView> hitTest(cocos2d::Vec2 point, cocos2d::Event * event) {
...
};
```

How can I implement this method from inside the View? It should return this VC's shared_ptr to outside?
Obviously, I **cannot** make_shared(this)

```
hitTest() {
...
    return make_shared<View>(this);
}
```

because it would break completely the logic: it just would create another smart pointer from the this raw pointer (that would be totally unrelated to owner's shared_ptr)
So how the view could know its external's shared_ptr and return it from inside the instance?

Comment: shared and unique pointers usually deal with ownership. How can be an instance owned by itself?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: Have you seen [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: @MohamadElghawi thanks!

Comment: @Angew thanks guys looks like that is the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mohamad Elghawi correctly pointed out, your class needs to be derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

```
#include <memory>

struct Shared : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Shared>
{
     std::shared_ptr<Shared> getPtr()
     {
         return shared_from_this();
     }
 };
```

Just to completely answer this questions, as link only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: how is it possible that Shared type is inherited from the template, templatized by the Shared type itself? i.e compiler should instantiate the enable_shared_from_this<Shared> template type before the Shared is defined but its publicly inherits its own child?

Comment: @barney: It's called the CRTP idiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @OnMyLittleDuck interestingly I just made a test. the enable_shared... class template - should be unfolding from <typename T> to a class containing ivar Shared * pointer somewhere inside. so its possible to define: 

class Shared;
class testdrive {
    Shared * t;
};

class Shared : public testdrive {
    
};
as Shared only inherits pointers to its own type from the testdrive - and all compiles ok

Comment: This answer needs a warning about using `shared_from_this()` on objects which are not managed by some `shared_ptr`. Downvoting until fixed ;-)

Comment: @Jan Henke what if I am using Poco::SharedPtr instead of std::shared_ptr, what should I use instead of enable_shared_from_this?

Comment: @XY Always prefer to use the standard library. I am not familiar with your particular library, so if you have to use it, consult the documentation.