# Can pointer 'this' be a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I have a question about the `this` pointer in C++.

If I create a pointer,

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> instance_1;
```

Is the `this` pointer of `instance_1` also a shared pointer?

The reason I ask this question is, if I start another thread in its method using pointer `this`. Will it copy the `shared_ptr`?

Comment: `this` is always a raw pointer. But your class can derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this` to allow its methods to return a `shared_ptr` of `this`

Comment: No.  But see [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711094/751579).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to return shared\_ptr to current object from inside the "this" object itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863240/how-to-return-shared-ptr-to-current-object-from-inside-the-this-object-itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the `this` pointer of `instance_1` also a shared pointer?

No. The `this` pointer is the pointer to the current instance of an object, it points to the same shared object as the shared pointer in this case. But it is itself not a `shared_ptr`. It is of type `SomeClass*`.

> The reason I ask this question is...

To create a `shared_ptr` from `this`, `SomeClass` must be derived from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). Then you can use;

> `shared_from_this()`; returns a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership of `*this`

When sharing state like this between threads, be careful of race conditions and locking issues etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot make `this` to be a shared pointer. Closest thing is to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and get shared pointer by calling:

```
this->shared_from_this();
```

details can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Another alternative would be to use intrusive shared pointer, like `boost::intrusive_ptr`, where `this` will not be shared pointer though but can be converted to one.

Answer (score 2):

No. Creating a shared pointer to an object does not make `this` in the object a shared pointer.

If you want to get a shared pointer from `this`, you might want to at least consider using [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Answer (score 0):

No, `this` is always a raw pointer.  If you want another thread to have a copy of the shared_ptr, you will have to give it `instance_1`.